# How do political leaders decide what to do next in a crisis?

Tags: armed-conflict, ukraine, foreign-policy, political-leaders

At present, politicians both in "the West" and in Russia may well be under the most extreme pressure of their entire careers. How do they all keep cool heads, and reach decisions about what to do next, as part of the Ukraine crisis? How do they ensure their next move best serves their own interests, while avoiding escalation and keeping as many options open as possible, especially that of diplomacy?

I can't believe that, for example, when the US president meets with his advisors, he is surrounded just by a bunch of trigger-happy gunslingers who would, if they could, always shoot first and ask questions later/never. Similarly, I cannot imagine that, when the Russian president meets with his advisors, they all down a few bottles of vodka first and only then get to work (Please excuse the stereotypes). Surely it's much more professional than that. Do both sides carefully weigh the risks of their decisions, including the potential risk of a nuclear confrontation, however "small"? Do they make every effort to consider the possible long-term consequences of what they do today?

I guess what I am asking, is: Are there reliable protocols in place which ensure that no politician can ever act on impulse alone, and that decisions are thought through before they are made final? Does the framework of political decision-making guarantee that?

Sometimes, it feels politicians make stupid moves, at least from the perspective of laypeople (and even some pundits). That's probably just the nature of politics. But surely politicians and their advisors know everything we know. Surely they never lose sight of the bigger picture - right?

Comment: "Are there reliable protocols in place which ensure that no politician can ever act on impulse alone?" -> in literally every political system other than a dictatorship

Comment: This is too open ended.  What nation are we talking about?  What decisions are we talking about?  Just the Ukraine war?  Other "big decisions"?  Many countries have elaborate checks and balance governing what politicians can do but they don't apply in all situations.  For example, nuclear launches - about as on point to this question as anything - are mostly perforce left up to the executive, otherwise a retaliatory counterstrike could not be guaranteed.  Please narrow the question else it is not answerable.  We had a question about Trump's capacity for a unilateral launch tho I didn't find it

Comment: From [help](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) : *You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. ... Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.*

Comment: Your answer: yes they do **probably**. What do you expect as an answer here? Detail of what they say when they are making decisions? Who knows?! Probably no one...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "...decisions are thought through before they are made final?" My impression is that this is done. Everyone involved seems to have been given a lot of thought into his/her decision. Not sure what you mean here really? Do you mean that many different eyes have given input and had a vote in the final decision? That will not necessary be the case in authoritarian countries like Russia.

Comment: @user253751 even dictators are surrounded by advisors.

Comment: @Allure "advisors" provide advice (that is the meaning of the term) and do not actually prevent people from doing stupid things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Think of navigating international relations safely as a rough analogy as someone driving a car.  Most cars have extensive security and safety systems but the expectation is that the driver is behaving rationally and competently.

A car may have an ABS to prevent brake lockups, but some drivers will pile on the brakes at the last moment and will still get into an accident.  Not all screw ups can be prevented by car safeties.

A car, especially as we get more into automation, may have all sorts of failsafes meaning to keep you safe.  "Don't drive in this snowstorm".  But what about the guy who just got bitten by a snow-rattlesnake in his backyard and needs to drive to the hospital?

Leaders, in democracies, typically have all sorts of checks and balances:

- They need to govern lawfully.  Those laws are passed with the consent of other parts of the government.  Often, yet another part reviews them for conformity to some form of constitution.  You can think of that as the mechanics and the DMV, checking that the car is OK to run.  Great now, now you have a well-maintained car.  Does that mean you can't run it into the ditch?  No.
- On the international stage, a leader has to be able to respond to emergencies, and not all contingencies will be covered by existing laws.  And the existing laws may not be applied well, and especially not *in time*.  A POTUS could for example state that he is declaring war on China.  Yes, Congress needs to approve that war, but will China sit by idly waiting for that declaration to be rejected?  No.
- A leader can often, as a last resort, be impeached, get a vote of non-confidence.  But they have plenty of leeway, time-wise to get their country in trouble first.  Think of that as a drunk driver.  Sure, they can lose their license, but first they can make a royal mess driving drunk.
- Protocols are only as good as those applying them.  I can't remember exactly where, but I read someone claiming that the Weimar Republic was admirable, *in theory*.  All sorts of liberal stuff and representation and shining rainbow unicorns.  But the  system wasn't followed through.  A lot of it hinges on customs and tradition, rather than rules and protocols:  the January 6th insurrection did not succeed because the US has a long tradition of democracy, not because its laws were so much better than a lot of states where coups *do* succeed.
- Akin to that snow-rattlesnake that just bit you, nuclear countries can need to take a launch-on-warning decision in minutes.  Therefore that decision needs to be taken by a few people, very quickly.

The main point of the analogy is that, rather than having a magical system preventing a horrible driver from getting into an accident in all conditions, we instead vet those drivers ahead of time.  Those that are not seen as worthy don't get a license.

**The stakes with leaders are very, very, high.  But happily, democracies have a much stricter vetting procedure:  elections, where *politicians* are transformed into *leaders*.**

In the final recourse, it is the electorate's role to make sure that their elected leaders are capable of performing the job competently and are not likely to get the country in trouble.  Look at Poland's PiS for example:  they're replacing the judges so they can, *protocol-wise*, do what they want.  Maybe don't elect someone with their type of demagoguery.

There is another further analogy:  despite all the safeguards drivers can drive dangerously but at the end of the day, it is their life, and their state, on the line.  Leaders, and their followers and implementers are ultimately also on the hook if they mess up.  So, if they have the intellectual capacity they will act with due caution, protocols or not.  No one is going to accuse Kim Jong-un of excessive niceness.  Nor is North Korea known for its excessive checks and balances on their leaders.  But Kim is probably not going to attack South Korea any time soon.

Last, regarding *decisions are thought through before they are made final?*

I recall reading somewhere that almost all wars start because of *miscalculations* by at least one side.  The attacker **thinks** they can win while the defender thinks they can hold out.  One side has to be wrong.  These decisions are not arrived at by sitting around and drinking vodka (one of Putin's electoral selling points early on was that he was abstemious, btw).  They're highly reasoned through, but... the reasoning is flawed, simple as that.  The flaw is not apparent to the party making the mistake until later.

- 1941 Japan.  Yes, we've thought it through and we can hit the US hard enough to have them declare a ceasefire.
- 2003 USA.  Yes, if we invade Iraq and then occupy it and reform their legal system to allow US companies to take over nationalized Iraqi oil companies, of course they'll be happy with it.
- 2022 Putin.  Ukrainians will welcome us as liberators.

These weren't spur of the moment decisions.  *They **made** every effort to consider the possible long-term consequences of what they did*.  Which isn't to say that these were ethical or correct decisions.  So I am unsure what exactly you are asking for.

Comment: "So I am unsure what exactly you are asking for." A lot of text to basically declare the question to be unclear. But a nice read.

Comment: Thank you. This does answer my question, even if it was somewhat fuzzy.

Answer (score 2):

You can look through the decision-making process for some weighty decisions in the past to see what it's like. Example: [the decision to send US marines to storm a house that Osama bin Laden supposedly lived in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_of_Osama_bin_Laden#Planning_and_final_decision).

US planners thought about all sorts of things, e.g.:

- Mounting a joint operation with Pakistan.
- Attacking the compound with stealth bombers, thereby never sending in marines.
- If bombers are used, how likely it is that there is collateral damage to other buildings in the area.
- If bombers are used and there is an underground bunker in the house (which could not be ruled out), how likely it is that "Osama" would survive anyway.
- What if the intelligence is wrong and Osama doesn't actually live in the house?
- How would Pakistan react even if the intelligence is right, since the raid involves projecting power into their territory?
- What if bin Laden surrenders? What if he fought back and is killed?

Yada yada blah blah. The section on Wikipedia is quite lengthy for a reason.

Ultimately the decision was made by one person - then US president Obama - but he drew on the expertise and advice of a lot of different people. Something similar to this is undoubtedly how major political decisions are made.